# sendmail configuration

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, sendmail

hello i have done the fol­low­ing :

1.install send­mail and con­fig­ure /etc/mail/sendmail.mc :
add com­ment to line

> DAEMON_OPTIONS(‘Family=inet,
>   Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp,
>   Addr=127.0.0.1′)dnl`

2.configure joomla mail server sit­ting = send­mail

3.php.ini :

> sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail –i
>   –t

mail server only work­ing if i send email from local server , but when am try­ing send email from web­site via Inter­net that not work­ing !!!
ANY HELP
information :
-i have an public ip and domain name .
-website and mail server (sendmail) in same server with ubuntu OS

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my original answer is wrong since you've stated that the web server and mail server exist on the same machine.  The problem is likely mail relay.  Sendmail is likely not configured to relay mail incoming from the web server.

Check `/var/log/mail.log`, `/var/log/mail.err` and `/var/log/mail.warn` and post the error messages when Joomla tries to mail.

---

Looks like sendmail is only listening on the loopback adapter.

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(‘Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1′)dnl`
```

Try.

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(‘Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=0.0.0.0′)dnl`
```

That said, be aware that if you openly relay mail, it won't be long before your mail server is blacklisted.  Please read some documentation on SMTP server best-practices.

Comment: i already tried to configure to `DAEMON_OPTIONS(‘Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=0.0.0.0′)dnl`` , same issue

Answer (score -1):

Have you run sendmailconfig so as to rebuild your sendmail.cf from sendmail.mc and restart sendmail ? (sendmailconfig does both)